# Permanently Active menu Color while in Sub-menu

Tags: css, wordpress, menu

My menu is Like This

```
<div class="menu1a">
<nav role="navigation" class="site-nav">

<ul class="main-nav" id="menu-main">
<li class="menu-item abc1" id="def1"><a>Home</a></li>
<li class="menu-item abc2" id="def2"><a>About Us</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li class="menu-item abcd1" id="defg1"><a>Corporate Overview</a></li>
<li class="menu-item abcd2" id="defg2"><a>Mission, Vision &amp; Core Values</a>    
</li>
<li class="menu-item abcd3" id="defg3"><a>Management</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="menu-item abc3" id="def3"><a>Services</a></li>
<li class="menu-item abc4" id="def4"><a>Know Hub</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li class="menu-item abcd4" id="defg4"><a>Articles</a></li>
<li class="menu-item abcd5" id="defg5"><a>Outsourcing Glossary</a></li>
<li class="menu-item abcd6" id="defg6"><a>Events</a></li>
<li class="menu-item abcd7" id="defg7"><a>Gallery</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="menu-item abc5" id="def5"><a>Clients</a></li>
<li class="menu-item abc6" id="def6"><a>Reviews</a></li>
<li class="menu-item abc7" id="def7"><a>Get Started</a></li>
<li class="menu-item abc8" id="def8"><a>Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>


</nav>
</div>

</div>
```

How do I give a Permanent color to my active menu item in Wordpress so that when a Sub-Menu Item is selected then its Parent menu is highlighted with the color #f00.

This is what I used for Menu Item :

```
ul li.current-menu-item a {
    color:#01abea;
}

ul li#current-menu-item a {
    color:#01abea;
}
```

And somebody suggested me to Use this for Sub-menu Item:

```
ul li ul.sub-menu li { color:#01abea;}
ul li ul#sub-menu li { color:#01abea;}
```

Can Anybody correct the last code for Submenu because its not working.

Comment: You need to post the CSS

Comment: My css Code is very Huge to be Posted!!

Comment: Could someone Please Help me out as Soon as Possible!!

Comment: Post only the relevant CSS, or else send us a link for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following class in your CSS. When you select the sub menu item, word-press automatically add this class to the relevant parent. So update this class with your color text.

```
.current-menu-parent, .current-menu-parent a
{
  color:#f00 !important;
}
```